# ld cannot find -lvulkan

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, compiling, libraries, vulkan

After successfully installing the LunarG Vulkan SDK (or so I thought) and setting the environment variables in the /etc/profile I still can't build the Vulkan samples. I followed very carefully the installation procedure in the documentation included with the SDK.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Nvidia 367.27.

All OpenGL samples build perfectly.

This are the variables I have set:

```
export VULKAN_SDK=/opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:$VULKAN_SDK/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

Tried rebooting my machine and checking the value of the `VULKAN_SDK` variable and it is still there.

```
$ echo $VULKAN_SDK
/opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64
```

My `VULKAN_SDK/lib` directory contains the following libvulkan libraries:

```
libvulkan.so
libvulkan.so.1
libvulkan.so.1.0.17
```

According to `ls -l` the first library points to the second one, and the second one points to the third one:

`ls -l` result:

[image]

Maybe I shouldn't install it in `/opt`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a build/linker command that is failing?

Comment: I am using the Makefiles provided, generally it would be ld -lvulkan but for some reason it won't find the libraries. I have only had this problem with this samples.

Comment: I'm trying to establish whether the non-standard library location is being picked up in the linker command line e.g. a `gcc  blah blah blah -L /opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64/lib` directive

Comment: As far is I can tell it just does `gcc something -lGL -lX11 ... -lvulkan` instead of the whole `gcc something -L /opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64/lib`. It can successfully find all the required libraries except for the vulkan ones, oddly enough in the makefile the vulkan lib is at the end of the sequence of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question,

I solved it by doing the following in `/usr/lib`

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64/lib/libvulkan.so.1.0.17 libvulkan.so.1.0.17
$ sudo ln -s /opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64/lib/libvulkan.so.1 libvulkan.so.1
$ sudo ln -s /opt/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/x86_64/lib/libvulkan.so libvulkan.so
```

Maybe not the best solution but it works for now.

Comment: You should be able to fix this by setting the LIBRARY_PATH: `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the SDK's libraries, you can use the [`libvulkan-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libvulkan-dev) package, which provides `-lvulkan` and can be installed with `sudo apt install libvulkan-dev`.